# Logging based on environment in .NetCore 2.2 using ILoggerProvider

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1, ilogger

I am working on .Net Core 2.2 logging mechanism.
While I was experimenting the logging based on environment.
So, I created two new appSettings.json files with respective environments along with appSettings.json present in the solution. One for Development, other for Production environment.

```
appsettings.json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      //"Default": "Debug",
      //"System": "Information",
      //"Microsoft": "Error"
    }
  }
}
```

appsettings.Development.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
     "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

appSettings.Production.json

```
 {
  "Logging": {
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft": "Critical"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Changed the StartUp.cs file

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
{

            Configuration = configuration;
            var currentEnvironment = env.EnvironmentName;
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{currentEnvironment}.json", optional: true);

}
```

Logging Method

```
public void LogExceptionToConsole()
{
            _logger.LogError("This is raised by error");
            _logger.LogCritical("This is raised by critical ");
}
```

And launchSettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:2131",
      "sslPort": 44388
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    },
    "DemoLoggingApplication": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I understand that environment specific appSettings would be taken the highest precedence.
And I have two questions

1) Does environment specific logging happens? If yes, then what could be the changes in the above logic.

2) When I ran the application in Development mode on `DemoLoggingApplication` profile. I can see all the `Information,Error & Critical` logs.

But when I changed the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` value from `Development` to `Production` for `DemoLoggingApplication` profile and ran the application I could again see both the logs of type `Error` & `Critical`.
   As, I've set that `Console` provider should only display `Critical` logs of type `Microsoft` category .I've been displayed `Errors` logs also.

Though I've read the Microsoft documents, I couldn't understand the prioritization. Could anyone explain me detail why I'm seeing both the logs.
   Am I missing any understanding. Please help me.

Thanks in advance

---

**Updated the question after Bob's answer**
It worked after changing the appsettings.json, appsettings.Development.json & appSettings.Production.json

appSettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information" 
    }
  }
}
```

appsettings.Development.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "Default": "Information" // newly
      }
    }
  }
}
```

appSettings.Production.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft": "Critical",
        "Default" :  "Critical" // newly added line
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I changed the environment to `Development`, I could log from `Information` but only after adding `Default` category to both Development and Production.

I just wanted to know why is this behavior?
And what's the impact of having maintaining `appsettings.json -> Logging` when we are having Development & Production settings.

Thanks

Comment: Initially in your appsettings.json  all loglevels including default are commented. That is why you are not seeing the use of having appsettings.json

Comment: Is it mandatory to have `Default` category in every provider? What happens if it's not given?

Comment: It's not mandatory. For a given Log Category if LogLevel is not mentioned in code/config, then it will look for LogLevel of Default Log Category in code/config. If that is also not available, then it takes Minimum Log Level setting as "Information".

Answer (score 1):

Environment specific logging happens.

In your example, both appsettings.Development.json and appsettings.Production.json defines LogLevel only for "Microsoft" category. But, the logging done from your code falls in a different Log Category whose LogLevel is not defined in code/config files. Hence, it takes default minimum log level as "Information" in both environments.

To see a difference, add "Default" key with different LogLevel settings in different environments as below:

appsettings.Development.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
     "Microsoft": "Information",
     "Default": "Error"
    }
  }
}
```

appSettings.Production.json

```
 {
  "Logging": {
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft": "Critical",
         "Default": "Critical"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working as expected but why should there be a default category for these providers? Could you please explain in detail about the working mechanism. Updated the question as well